# Authentication failed user not found in active directory

Tags: active-directory, subversion-edge

Having this problem with subversion edge integration with Active Directory and I'm not sure whether it's setting issue or something else.  Here is my setting for AD Authentication.

```
LDAP authentication against an LDAP server:  X
LDAP Security Level: None
LDAP Server Host: myserver.mydomain.net
LDAP Server Port: 3268
LDAP Base DN: DC=mydomain,DC=net
LDAP Bind DN: myuser@mydomain.net
LDAP Bind Password: MyPassword
LDAP Login Attribute: sAMAccountName
LDAP Search Scope: Sub
LDAP Filter: (&(objectClass=user))
Console LDAP Authentication: Allow LDAP users to access the management console
Console LDAP Authentication Helper Port: 49156
```

Subversion Edge is installed on CentOS 6.4 64 bit.

We are using windows 2003 Server with very basic AD setting.  We don't even use OU for the setting.  However, when user trying to login, we keep getting this error.

```
[Tue Feb 25 19:23:58.794388 2014] [auth_basic:error] [pid 3420] [client 127.0.0.1:39800] AH01618: user myuser@mydomain.net not found: /
```

Of course, myuser@mydomain.net does exist in the AD.  I'm scratching my head feeling very confused.  Anyone can give me a pointer/suggestion? Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gosh.

Spent the whole day trying to figure out what the heck is going on with my subversion Edge integration with AD.  Pulling my hair apart and couldn't figure what's going on.  I was checking around my Active Directory information that was pulled out using JXplorer.  Then I noticed that my sAMAccountName information is stored in the format of "myuser" only not "myuser@mydomain.net", which was how I'd been trying to login to.  As soon as I changed that, boom it works.

Hope this help the rest of you folks for future reference with debugging this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that, this helped me get up and running in my test system - Subversion Edge on a Windows 2012 and the settings are largely the same.

I created a specific user for binding to AD.